# Why can't we use resistance formulae in Thévenin's theorem, when a dependent source is connected?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

According to my textbook, if a dependent source is connected to the circuit (while calculating Thévenin's equivalent resistance), we can't use the series and parallel connections formulae for calculating the resistance.
My question is, why are we not allowed to do so?

Comment: If you try to solve it independently, you will get infinite solution.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that a dependent source can behave exactly like a resistor. Consider a voltage dependent current source of 1 mA per volt. That will behave like a 1 kΩ resistor when its terminals are connected.

In any other configuration it may somewhat behave like a resistor so, you can't dispose of it like you would a fixed voltage or current source.

Comment: And, if we just consider a general circuit (not talking about thévenin's theorem here) which has a dependent source in it, can we use the usual series and parallel resistance formulae to find the net resistance? Or is that not allowed there too?

Comment: You can still series and parallel real resistors. Nothing changes there.